# Legitimacy of rulings accepted through spontaneous rabbinic gatherings

Tags: halacha-theory, beit-din-court, sanhedrin

The Torah prescribes settling the law in a very special place:

> "If a case is too baffling for you to decide, be it controversy over homicide, civil law, or assault—matters of dispute in your courts, you shall promptly repair **to the place that the LORD your God will have chosen**, and appear before the Levitical priests, or the magistrate in charge at the time, and present your problem." [Deuteronomy.17.8-9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.17.7-9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en&aliyot=0)

In my understanding of the passage, the Torah prescribes to authorize all future Halochos in a dedicated place (aka Sanhedrin), following certain official legal procedures.

IIRC, all halachic disputes in the Talmud occur outside the official Sanhedrin, even after its exile: in shuls, private homes and penthouses, on private journeys, etc.

Many ***ruling*** Halohos are ruled in such spontaneous gatherings, however, it is never mentioned that the gathering had the official status of a Sanhedrin, or that certain official procedures took place.

What is the legitimacy of such gatherings, and why would a decision of a spontaneous gathering even if the majority supports it, obligate others?

*NB: I do not use examples, because, as I mentioned, IIRC, on the paper, all Talmudic arguments take place outside Sanhedrin.*

Comment: Also, the Torah doesn't say the law can only be settled in one place. After all, the Torah also says to have courts in every city. It means that there is an ultimate final authority in the Sanhedrin, if lower courts deadlock or don't know the answer. But rulings outside the Sanhedrin are perfectly valid.

Comment: https://www.aish.com/jl/m/pm/48932007.html?mobile=yes.   "Since the Talmud was accepted by all Israel, it is the final authority in all questions of Torah law. Since such universal acceptance is a manifestation of God's will, one who opposes the teachings of the Talmud is like one who opposes God and His Torah. All later codes and decisions are binding only insofar as they are derived from the Talmud."

Comment: First of all, we do have examples of things being decided in the Lishkas Hagazis; see Peah 2:6 for an example. (The debate between Hillel and Bnei Beseirah was most likely there too, the more so since it involved the Korban Pesach.) Second, what N.T. said.

Comment: @N.T. You confuse setting the global Halacha (think of the Congress) vs solving cases in municipal courts. The Halacha can not be set in towns' courts.

Comment: @Meir Yes, occasionally the scribe was in the Lishkah, but not the Sanhedrin. I asked a question once and did not find a case that was brought before the Sanhedrin. Also see my reply to nt.

Comment: The rulings of each city's court is binding on that city. See Yevamos 13, iirc.

Comment: @N.T. Are you saying that a city court is legislating laws, that could be different from other cities? In my understanding, they don't have that power (in theory, according to Rambam's Hil. Sanhedrin), and they only judge according to the Sanhedrin's laws.

Comment: Yes. A city court's ruling is binding in its city, even if others disagree. This is the basis for the sugya of *Lo Sisgodedu*.

Comment: @Chatzkel Are you sure Aish is referring to Talmud Bavli? Because from what I recall, those in Israel (of all countries to mention) followed Yerushalmi until the early Geonic period, where halachic authors outside Israel pressured those within to adopt Bavli. It definitely was not "universal acceptance" by historical standards.

Comment: @elie yes they are referring to Bavli "Therefore, whenever they disagree with the Talmud, decisions found in the Jerusalem Talmud, Midrash and Tosefta are ignored". Perhaps they're only referring to the time after it was universally accepted

Comment: @Chatzkel I took a look at the article... I am confused at best sadly. My understanding is that prior to the Geonim, there were few (if any) codified rulings (Sifrei Halacha), so to say "Bavli was dominant!" is judging 2/2 codified books. Certainly nowadays it is the dominant source for Halacha, but I do take issue with the conclusions derived from that passage, especially considering the Yerushalmi's political past.